# Linear Programming - Unique number of categories

Tags: r, linear-programming

**TL;DR:** I am trying to find the "cheapest" set of items in a collection that satisfy certain linear constraints. However, every element can be part of multiple "categories" and I also want to have a mix of those unique categories and I'm not quite sure if this can be implemented in a LP way or not and in case how to approach it.

**Example - Part 1**
Let's say I have 7 items that have different costs and different values associated to them.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lpSolve)

# Fake data
kd = tibble(
  Item = 1:7,
  Cost = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4),
  Value =c(1, 1, 3, 4, 6, 3, 2),
  Type = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
)
```

I want to pick 3 of those elements so that Cost is minimized and their Value is >= 5. I can easily do this with `lp` with the following code:

```r
# Objective function
knapsack.obj = kd$Cost

# Constraints
knapsack.con = matrix(
  c(
    rep(1, nrow(kd)), 
    kd$Value 
  ),
  nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE
)
knapsack.dir = c("==", ">=")
knapsack.rhs = c(3, 5)

# Solve
knapsackSolution = lp("min", knapsack.obj, knapsack.con, knapsack.dir, knapsack.rhs, all.bin = TRUE) 

# Results
kd[knapsackSolution$solution == 1, ]
```

As expected this returns Item 1, 2 and 3 that have a combined Value=5 and are obviously minimizing the price.

**Example - Part 2**

The extra complication I don't quite know how to solve now is adding code for making sure the items picked they come from at least 2 unique categories.
Now the solution I'd expect is Item 1, 2 and 4 (or 1, 3 and 4) that have still a combined cost of 3 and a value of 6 (or 8) that is >= 5 but are not all "A" elements but contain also Item 4 that is a "B" element.

Any idea on how to implement this in a LP framework?

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematical Model

If we introduce a zero-one (data) matrix

```
Category[i,j] = 1  if item i has type j
                0  otherwise
```

and a binary variable:

```
y[j] = 1 if an item with type j is selected
       0 otherwise
```

we can develop a simple mathematical model:

[image]

The blue colored symbols represent data while the red ones are decision variables.

Note that the variable `y[j]` can be relaxed to be continuous between 0 and 1.

The advantage of first writing down a mathematical model is that it is easier to reason about than a bunch of R code (at least for me).

### Implementation

I use OMPR here for two reasons:

- Direct way to implement the model in an equation based fashion. We stay closer to the mathematical model.
- Access to better solvers than LpSolve.

Here is the R code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ROI)
library(ROI.plugin.symphony)
library(ompr)
library(ompr.roi)

# Fake data
kd = tibble(
  Item = 1:7,
  Cost = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4),
  Value =c(1, 1, 3, 4, 6, 3, 2),
  Type = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
)

Types <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
Category <- 1*outer(kd$Type,Types,FUN="==")
Type <- 1:length(Types)

numItems <- 3
MinValue <- 5
MinItems <- 2

m <- MIPModel() %>%
  add_variable(x[i], i=kd$Item, type="binary") %>%
  add_variable(y[j], j=Type, type="binary") %>%
  add_constraint(sum_expr(x[i], i=kd$Item) == numItems) %>% 
  add_constraint(sum_expr(kd$Value[i]*x[i], i=kd$Item) >= MinValue) %>% 
  add_constraint(y[j] <= sum_expr(Category[i,j]*x[i], i=kd$Item), j=Type) %>% 
  add_constraint(sum_expr(y[j], j=Type) >= MinItems) %>% 
  set_objective(sum_expr(kd$Cost[i]*x[i], i=kd$Item),"min") %>% 
  solve_model(with_ROI(solver = "symphony", verbosity=1))

cat("Status:",solver_status(m),"\n")
cat("Objective:",objective_value(m),"\n")
m$solution
```

Probably the most complex part here is the calculation of the Category matrix.

### Solution

The solution looks like:

```
Status: optimal 
Objective: 3 
x[1] x[2] x[3] x[4] x[5] x[6] x[7] y[1] y[2] y[3] y[4] y[5] 
   1    1    0    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we know that the solution must have k = 3 elements restrict each group to have k-1 or fewer elements forcing at least 2 groups to be used.

```
incid <- +outer(unique(kd$Type), kd$Type, "==")
ntypes <- nrow(incid)

knapsack.con = rbind(
    rep(1, nrow(kd)), 
    kd$Value,
    incid)

k <- 3
knapsack.dir = c("==", ">=", rep("<=", ntypes))
knapsack.rhs = c(k, 5, rep(k-1, ntypes))
res <- lp("min", knapsack.obj, knapsack.con, knapsack.dir, knapsack.rhs, all.bin = TRUE) 

res$status
## [1] 0

res$solution
## [1] 1 1 0 1 0 0 0
```

### Simplification

As we discussed in the comments, for this particular data we can omit the last 4 constraints since they are always satsified as there is only one element in each of the last 4 groups.

```
res2 <- lp("min", knapsack.obj, knapsack.con[1:3, ], knapsack.dir[1:3], 
  disknapsack.rhs[1:3], all.bin = TRUE) 

res2$status
## [1] 0

res2$solution
## [1] 1 1 0 1 0 0 0
```

### Generalizing

As we discussed in the comments, to generalize let us suppose we want at least 3 different categories in the solution rather than 2.  In this particular data we could simply require the solution have no more than 1 of each category but in general that will not work so let us take all combinations of groups 2 at a time and produce the constraints shown below.  5 is the total number of categories in the problem and 2 is one less than the number of categories required to be in the solution.

```
combos <- combn(5, 2, function(x) colSums(incid[x, ]))
```

For each of those constraints, i.e. each row in combos, we require that it be less or equal to 2 in order to exclude any solution having only 1 or 2 categories.  We then construct the LP in a similar manner as before adding the remaining constraints.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this! Am I right in saying that in this "dummy" case I created it will work you are right, but if instead we have a dataframe with let's say 50 categories and I want at least 10 items picked in 5 categories this won't work anymore? I can't just force all 50 categories to have less than 4 elements because potentially the best solution is one formed of 6 in A, 1 in B, 1 in C, 1 in D and 1 in E.

Comment: If there were 50 categories in the problem and at least 5 required in the solution then there are choose(50, 4) = 230300 ways to choose 4 categories among the 50 and none of those combinations may contain the entire solution so add that many constraints.  I don't know about lpSolve but good LP codes can handle problems that large.

Comment: Note that for specific known distributios of the categories there may be simplificaitons.  For example, in the problem there is only one category having more than one element. It would have been good enough to ensure that just that category have 2 or fewer elements reducing the number of constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, we do not have to force the solution to have `k-1` or fewer elements from each group. We can instead force each group to have at most `g_i-1` elements where `g_i` is the number of elements in each group.

Here is the implementation:

```
library(purrr)
library(lpSolve)
library(fastmatch)

# Fake data
  kd = tibble(
  Item = 1:7,
  Cost = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4),
  Value =c(1, 1, 3, 4, 6, 3, 2),
  Type = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
)

# number of elements to choose
k = 3

  type_match <- fmatch(kd$Type, unique(kd$Type))
  unique_cat <- unique(type_match)

  add_con <- map(unique_cat,function(x) {
    type_match[type_match != x] = 0
    type_match[type_match > 0] = 1
    return(type_match)}) %>% 
    do.call(rbind,.)

  knapsack.obj = kd$Cost
  knapsack.con = 
    rbind(
      rep(1, nrow(kd)), 
      kd$Value,
      add_con
    )
rhs_add <- apply(add_con, 1, function(x) ifelse(sum(x)>1,sum(x) - 1,1))

  knapsack.dir = c("==", ">=", rep("<=",length(rhs_add)))
  knapsack.rhs = c(k, 5, rhs_add)

  knapsackSolution = lp("min", 
                        knapsack.obj, 
                        knapsack.con, 
                        knapsack.dir, 
                        knapsack.rhs, 
                        all.bin = TRUE) 
  knapsackSolution$solution
>   knapsackSolution$solution
[1] 1 1 0 1 0 0 0
```